# How do I deploy my project to mainnet beta?

Tags: anchor

Please what is the most secure
way to deploy to mainnet , considering the upgrade authority

Comment: please elaborate the question so that it asks one clear, concise question.  as worded it is ambiguous and alludes to many possible questions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In order to deploy a program you need to write a program first (Rust,C,C++...) [hello-world example](https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/examples)

Once you have the program coded you have to compile it using [Solana bpf](https://crates.io/crates/solana-cargo-build-bpf). follow this [guide](https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/developing-rust#how-to-build)

this will generate a `.so` file which you can deploy on the mainnet.

```
solana program deploy <SO_FILEPATH>
```

For more information

https://docs.solana.com/cli/deploy-a-program

Or you can simplify this process and use [Anchor](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor) framework, which I recommend.

Hope this helps!